# CSS padding для table-row

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, уважаемые специалисты, помогите с проблемой, очень нужно. Есть таблица из `div`-ов в ней одна колонка и несколько строк, вот упрощенный вид:

```css
.vcom_tab {display:table; border-collapse: collapse;}
.vcom_tab > div {display: table-row; border: dashed 1px #ddd; padding:5px;}
```

```html
<div class="vcom_tab">
 <div>Комментарии</div>
 <div>
   <div>Арсен</div>
   <div>Спасибо</div>
 </div>
 <div>
   <div>Михаил</div>
   <div>Незачто</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgfk2L3z/22/)

Как применить к `table-row` свойство `padding`?

Знаю из мануала, что это свойство не применимо к `tr`, как выйти из ситуации?

Comment: Необходимо именно `table-row`? Может быть все же нужен `table-cell`. Или как вариант содержимое div ов, к которым применяется `table-row`, обернуть еще в блоки и уже им задавать отступы

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, `table-row` не обязательно, просто если его изменить на `table-cell` , то все строки преобразуются в колонки и вся таблица устремится вправо  вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/dgfk2L3z/36/ а мне нужно вниз, если не найду простого решения воспользуюсь вторым Вашим предложением.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```css
.vcom_tab {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.vcom_tab > div {
  display: table-row;
  border: dashed 1px #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

.vcom_tab > div span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="vcom_tab">
  <div>Комментарии</div>
  <div>
    <div><span>Арсен</span></div>
    <div><span>Спасибо</span></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div><span>Михаил</span></div>
    <div><span>Незачто</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```